# Can't get Laravel 4.2 to work / 404

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-4

I've tried installing and reinstalling and going through dozens of possible solutions and nothing has worked.

I installed Laravel 4.2 to `/var/www/project`.

I then created a new virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        # Don't show directory index
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And enabled it with:

```
sudo a2ensite project.conf
```

And restarted apache2. However, when I go to my domain, all I get is a 404:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work if you try /index.php ?

Comment: @Artisan72 Nope, still get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

I had to:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, add this

```
ServerName projectname
```

below `<VirtualHost>`

Add the line

```
127.0.0.1   projectname
```

to the `etc/hosts` file. So it should work without having to disable other sites.

Restart your apache and test it with `http://projectname`.